# how i can traverse the xml path dynamically in antscript?

Tags: ant, xml-parsing

Could anyone tell me, how can I traverse the xml path dynamically in antscript? If the parent tag is given from command line arguement. with this , i have to form child tag path ..access the xml file , to pull the value form the formed xml tag path.

```
ant -DId=abc
```

Given file is

```
<abc>
 <Age>16</Age>
</abc>
```

Is this correct to give output 16?

```
<echo>${${Id}.Age}</echo>
```

Answer (score 0):

ANT is not a scripting language, and properties within properties is unfortunately not supported :-(

My suggested solution is an embedded [groovy script](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task)

```
<target name="parse">
    <groovy>
        def data = new XmlSlurper().parse(new File("data.xml"))

        println data.Age
    </groovy>
</target>
```

Conveniently (in your case) the groovy xml parser ignores the name of the root tag, meaning you don't have to pass it as a parameter.

See also the following similar question:

- [How to <foreach> in a <macrodef>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14457360/how-to-foreach-in-a-macrodef/)